# Scheduled job is not stopping

Tags: python, schedule

I am using python `schedule` module ([documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)) to schedule a task. The script is running on a server, The script is triggered via API call. For testing purposes, I set the schedule to run every 5 minute and it worked fine as It should.

The problem arise when I ran the script next time with a different job at a different schedule/time. I can't see any effect of the current schedule. Instead, I am getting the output of the previously running job (which is running every 5 minutes). So what I need to know is, how to stop jobs which are scheduled in previously and replace them with latest schedule.

Comment: You use `job.cancel()` to cancel a job, but if you have modified the script. you'll usually want to kill the script and restart it.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I modified the script. Could you tell me how to kill and restart the script?

Comment: How did you start it?  What operating system?  Are you using an IDE?

Comment: The script running on a server (AWS) I don't have direct access to that, First I had to push the script to a repository, then trigger the script via calling an endpoint. @TimRoberts

Comment: Then I don't know.  You'll have to investigate the APIs you used to start the script.  There must be a way to stop it.